# Batch Scripting - Missing Characters

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am in the process of trying to create a script that will pull the first two characters of a file name from the file, make a directory containing those two characters (they are numbers, by the way) and ultimately place the original files into those folders. I was able to partially make this happen using the following lines of code (without the extra content)

```
IF EXIST 01* (MKDIR 01)
IF EXIST 02* (MKDIR 02)
IF EXIST 01* (MOVE 01* 01)
IF EXIST 02* (MOVE 02* 02)
```

This is obviously inefficient and requires editing of the script if I have more than N amount of files. I then did some digging and I found this script, which I tried to modify unsuccessfully to fit my needs

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R %%g IN (*) DO (
    SET fileName=%%~ng
    MKDIR !fileName:~2!
)
```

This script completes sort of. My test file names look like 0102.txt, 0203.txt, 0304.txt, and so forth. Instead of the script grabbing the first part being 01, 02, 03, etc, it grabs  the second part being 02, 03, 04, etc and cuts off the first two characters. I've performed an echo within the script, and I can even physically see it removing the first two characters. It is weird because I can even do

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R %%g IN (*) DO (
    SET fileName=%%~ng
    MKDIR !fileName!
    REN !fileName! !fileName:~2!
)
```

and I still end up with the same results. Does anyone have any ideas on fixing this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to your problem is the syntax of the substringing facility

```
set avar=%bvar:~start,length%
```

where `%` may be `!` if appropriate,
`start` is the start position, starting at "character 0".
`start` may be negative, meaning "this number of characters from the end of %bvar%"
`,length`  may be omitted meaning 'the rest of the string from `start`
`,length`  may be negative meaning to "this number of characters from the end of %bvar%"

That should allow you to solve the problem.

Comment: I will give this a shot here in a second. I've been busy with work and whatnot, so I haven't had a chance to come look here.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I forgot about the initial modifier when I borrowed the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated the scope of your numbered files but this will handle 01* - 09*

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,9) do if exist 0%%a* (md 0%%a 2>nul & move 0%%a* 0%%a)
```

An extra added line will handle from 10* to 99*

```
for /L %%a in (10,1,99) do if exist %%a* (md %%a 2>nul & move %%a* %%a)
```

Comment: I tried the FOR /L first. I couldn't figure out how to set it to pull the correct information because FOR /L IN (1,1,9) tends to only pull 1, 2, 3, etc. My files are listed as 01, 02, 03, etc. The reason for this is because they never go over 99 and it keeps the files listed in a specific order. I do appreciate the input though, and I will give this code a shot too.

Comment: I also just recalled that the reason I was using the other setup was so that the script was more universal for different sets of files. And I just noticed your initial 0, which would expand to allow 01, 02, 03, etc. Again, thank you for your coding, but I think the previous answer will serve my purposes better.